# Get ViewController from Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uistoryboard

I have two ViewControllers, which aren`t (directly) connected with a Segue. But I want to change a String in the second VC, which i get in the first one. My try was:

```
    #import "secondViewController.h"

    @interface firstViewController ()
    @property NSString* originalString;
    @end

    @implementation firstViewController

    -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
        secondViewController* svc = [secondViewController new];
        svc.anotherString = self.originalString;    
    }
```

But it dosent work, because I've only created a instance of the second VC, so the value was not saved. Also I can`t use the Storyboard ID, because I use Xcode 5.

I have a menuVC from which you can get to the firstVC and the secondVC. And from the firstVC I can go back (with the navigationbackbarbutton) to the menu. so: menu->firstVC->menu. menu->secondVC->...->menu

My try with StoryboardID:

```
    -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

        secondViewController* svc =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVCSrorybradID"];

        svc.anotherString = self.originalString;    
    }
```

Comment: How do you get from the first to the second VC ?

Comment: ? why you can't use storyboard id ???

Comment: Are you asking why originalString isn't updated when you change svc.anotherString?

Comment: Yes, thats my question iani

Comment: Don't use `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:]`. Since this is in a view controller you can use the view controller's storyboard property: `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"secondVCSrorybradID"]`. And is your storyboard ID really `secondVCSrorybradID`? Two misspellings in a single ID? It must be an exact match, letter for letter, and have the correct upper/lower case, or it will fail to load the view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your data successively through your `UIViewController`s navigation. If, for example, you have a navigation like `FirstVC > SecondVC > ThirdVC` :

In your FirstVC.m, use :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    ((SecondVCClass*) segue.destinationViewController).secondVCString = _firstVCString;
}
```

With `secondVCString` being a `@property` in your second ViewController.

In your SecondVC.m, use :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    ((ThirdVCClass*) segue.destinationViewController).thirdVCString = _secondVCString;
}
```

With of course `thirdVCString` being a `@property` in your third ViewController.

---

**Edit:**

As you updated your question, here is what I suggest :

- In your MenuVC, add this :

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *importantString;
  ```
- In your FirstVC and SecondVC, add this :

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, weak) MenuVCClass *menu;
  ```
- When you push to FirstVC or SecondVC, use `prepareForSegue` to set the destination's view controller `menu` property to your menu :

  ```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

      if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FirstSegue"])
          ((FirstVC*) segue.destinationViewController).menu = self;
      else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondSegue"])
          ((SecondVC*) segue.destinationViewController).menu = self;
  }
  ```
- In FirstVC or SecondVC, you can change the `NSString` value from your menu using `_menu.importantString = @"";`

Comment: thanks, but my first and my sec on VC goes both from another VC so when I get back to my menu the method "prepareForSegue" won't be called.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your app's structure ? Something like FirstVC -- SecondVC -- etc.

Comment: YES it works!! thanks :D Not exactly like you but it was your main idea with the menuVC thanks soooooooooo much!! §> U

Answer (score 11):

you can pass the string to second view controller with this code.

```
secondViewController* svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your Second VC's Storyboad ID"];
svc.anotherString = self.originalString;    
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

//you have to create anotherString property in second View Controller's .h File.

now you can get the string of originalString to second VC. Now you can get this value back second VC to first VC.

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use `new` to create a view controller.

If you're using storyboards but not using segues, you can still create a view controller from the storyboard and invoke it.

Use the method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to create an instance of the target view controller. The set the properties you want to set, and finally make a call to display it (present it modally, push it onto the navigation stack, or whatever is appropriate for your program.)

Comment: Can't use a storyboard ID you mean? Why? You said "because I use Xcode 5", which does not make any sense.

Comment: but i haven't any storryboard ID, really...  I've only Title

Comment: Ok, but you can (and should) assign a storyboard ID to any scene in your s storyboard. This is supported from Xcode 4.0 to the current version, 5.0.2

Comment: Dude, you need to write sentences that other people can understand if you actually want help. "It wouldn't be saved" is not one of those sentences.